# My Profile note board access in code

Tags: my-profile

Where is the note board data stored in SharePoint and can I access the data from an other site collection. If so can I add notes to a persons note board in code from a different site collection?

Comment: Did you achieve this? I have a similar requirement :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [**social comment manager class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.socialdata.socialcommentmanager_members.aspx) which will help you to achieve this.

1. You can add comments using the function Addcomment with the argument of URI.
2. You can use the function GetComments with the argument of userprofile to retrieve all the comments of the particular user in my site.
3. You can also use the function GetComments with the argument of URI, which helps in retrieving all the comments of all users given to a SharePoint page or library. The URI needs to be the document library or the page path.